# pytest layout import incompatibilty

Tags: python, import, package, python-import, pytest

I want to make a module following this layout in python 3 :

```
test_import
├── __init__.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sub_module
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test2.py
    └── test1.py
```

In that way I can make an other directory `test` beside src to use `pytest`.

And I want to be able to import test2.py in that way :

```
from test_import.sub_module import test2
```

If all the files `__init__.py` are empty I can import `test2` that way :

```
from test_import.src.sub_module import test2
```

I tried to put this code in the first `__init__.py` :

```
from .src import sub_module
from .src import test1
```

I get this error :

```
>>> import test_import
>>> test_import.sub_module
<module 'test_import.src.sub_module' from '/usr/local/lib/python-dataswati/test_import/src/sub_module/__init__.py'>
>>> test_import.sub_module.test2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'test_import.src.sub_module' has no attribute 'test2'
```

but I can use `test_import.test1`

### first clue

I can make this example work by filling `test_import/src/sub_module/__init__.py` with :

```
from . import test2
```

But I'd rather like not to specify it for all the files in my folder.

How should I proceed ?